# MySQL CAST() causes significant performance hit

Tags: mysql, casting

So I ran the following in the MySQL console as a control test to see what was holding back the speed of my query.

```sql
SELECT bbva_deductions.ded_code, SUBSTRING_INDEX(bbva_deductions.employee_id, '-' , -1) AS tt_emplid, 
                bbva_job.paygroup, bbva_job.file_nbr, bbva_deductions.ded_amount 
                FROM bbva_deductions 
                LEFT JOIN bbva_job 
                ON CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(bbva_deductions.employee_id, '-' , -1) AS UNSIGNED) = bbva_job.emplid LIMIT 500
```

It took consistently around 4 seconds to run. *(seems very high for only 500 rows)*. Simply removing the `CAST` within the `JOIN` decreased that to just `0.01` seconds.

In this context, why on earth is `CAST` so slow?

Here is the output of an `EXPLAIN` for this query:

[image]

And the same for the query without a `CAST`:

[image]

`EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

[image]

Comment: Sorry i should have been clear. It did not fix the issue, adding CAST to the alias did not affect the query in any negative way. It is being stored as a VARCHAR. The issue is that i need MySQL to compare the data as an integer, which it wont do since I use SUBSTRING_INDEX. The bbva_job table contains leading zeros while the bbva_deductions table does not so I cant compare them as strings.

Comment: If `bbva_job.emplid` is a `VARCHAR`, then indexes which have been built upon it will be in lexicographic order (based on the column's collation).  To compare based on the integer values represented by the column will necessarily mean that the indexes cannot be used.  You should store this column using an integer data type.  Furthermore, you really should store the related component of `bbva_deductions.employee_id` (i.e. that after the final `-` character) in its own integer column too, ideally also indexed.  It seems that you have made some very fundamental design errors.

Comment: I see, it would appear that I certainly have. I did not think about it from that angle but it makes sense. If youd like to post that ill happily make it best answer. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 7):

As documented under [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - To retrieve rows from other tables when performing joins. MySQL can use indexes on columns more efficiently if they are declared as the same type and size. In this context, [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) and [`CHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) are considered the same if they are declared as the same size. For example, `VARCHAR(10)` and `CHAR(10)` are the same size, but `VARCHAR(10)` and `CHAR(15)` are not.
>
> Comparison of dissimilar columns may prevent use of indexes if values cannot be compared directly without conversion. Suppose that a numeric column is compared to a string column. For a given value such as `1` in the numeric column, it might compare equal to any number of values in the string column such as `'1'`, `' 1'`, `'00001'`, or `'01.e1'`. This rules out use of any indexes for the string column.

In your case, you are attempting to join on a comparison between a substring (of a string column in one table) and a string column in another table.  An index can be used for this operation, however the comparison is performed lexicographically (i.e. treating the operands as strings, even if they represent numbers).

By explicitly casting one side to an integer, the comparison is performed numerically (as desired) - but this requires MySQL to [implicitly convert the type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html) of the string column and therefore it is unable to use that column's index.

You have hit this road bump because your schema is poorly designed.  You should strive to ensure that all columns:

1. are encoded using the data types that are most relevant to their content; and
2. contain only a single piece of information — see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

At the very least, your `bbva_job.emplid` should be an integer; and your `bbva_deductions.employee_id` should be split so that its parts are stored in separate *(appropriately-typed)* columns.  With appropriate indexes, your query will then be considerably more performant.